# Can't use mouse properly when running vim in tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

I'm running VIM in tmux,

When I'm try to select a range of texts in VIM, the mouse kept resetting its position, thus I can only select one line (the last line where mouse occurs).

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are two settings that you need to configure for this to work.

1. In your `.vimrc` add:

   ```
   set ttymouse=xterm2
   set mouse=a
   ```
2. In your `.tmux.conf` add:

   ```
   set -g mouse on
   ```

You will then be able to use the mouse to select blocks of text, resize splitted windows, ...

Comment: Hmm, mouse is slower in tmux, I can feel that, but it works anyway

Comment: Try to set ttymouse=xterm2 in your vimrc. For my setup (urxvt-unicode, tmux) it vastly improved the speed and responsiveness of mouse selecting in vim/tmux.

Comment: @imbaer Thanks, the mouse did not work at all in vim until I set that var as well.

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer, tmux.conf should now use `set -g mouse on`

Comment: Note that the ttymouse option was removed in neovim: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2725

Answer (score 9):

The answer by @jasonwryan won't work as of tmux 2.1 since the several mouse options were merged into one configuration called `mouse`.

The new approach is:

1. In your `.vimrc` add:

   ```
   set ttymouse=xterm2
   set mouse=a
   ```
2. In your `tmux.conf` add:

   ```
   set -g mouse on
   ```